# Accessing specific values in String Array in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I'm trying to make an Android app which parses a XML file with a lot of entries, but it will be ranged by user-defined zones.

The zones names are included in a string-array zone-list:

```
<string-array name="zone-list">
<item>Zone 1</item>
<item>Zone 2</item>
<item>Zone 3</item>
<item>Zone 4</item>
</string-array>
```

and I use this MultiSelectListPreference:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
        android:key="zone_sel"
        android:title="Zones"
        android:summary="Select zones"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/zones"
        android:entries="@array/zone-list"
        android:entryValues="@array/zone-list" />
```

Every item in the array is converted into a CheckBox item.

The problem is that now I need to acces the Boolean value of each item in order to interact with it in the code, in order to check if the Zone 1 information is wanted to be showed or not.

How could I do it?

Thanks in advance